# Cyclic referencing doesn't seem work in event handler function

Tags: javascript, events, this, cyclic-reference

I have an object called `paperClass` (even though I know, classes don't exist in JavaScript). This is containing a reference to a `divElement`. Now, by hovering the `divElement` I want to get a reference to the `paperClass` object. I tried it the following way:

```
function paperClass(){
    this.divElement = $("#divElementID");
    this.divElement.paperElement = this;
    this.divElement.hover(this.handleHover);
    console.log(this.divElement.attr("id"));    // -> divElementID
    console.log(this.divElement.paperElement);    // -> paperClass Object
}

paperClass.prototype.handleHover = function(event){
    console.log(this.id);    // -> divElementID
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));    // -> divElementID
    console.log(this.paperElement);     // -> undefined (which seems ok to me)
    console.log($(this).paperElement);  // -> undefined (WHY????)
}
```

I also tried the `.attr()` and `$data()` methods. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
console.log($(this).paperElement);  // -> undefined (WHY????)
```

has the `paperElement` property undefined because it was only present in the specific jQuery object you bound to `this.divElement`.

If you created a new jQuery object, it will only have its default properties set by the jQuery library.

Try this instead:

```
function paperClass(){
    this.divElement = $("#divElementID");
    this.divElement[0].paperElement = this; // change this line
    this.divElement.hover(this.handleHover);
    console.log(this.divElement.attr("id"));
    console.log(this.divElement.paperElement);
}

paperClass.prototype.handleHover = function(event){
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.paperElement);
}
```

Comment: Hi Matteo, THX for your Answer. "this" is already pointing at the divElement. this.id returns the correct id. Therefore this.divElement doesn't work either... unfortunately.

Comment: Cool :-) You saved me much time and getting frustrated. Do you have any explanation for having to this in such a strange way?

Comment: It is not strange, please read my answer again: `if you created a new jQuery object, it will only have its default properties set by the jQuery library.`, but I think this should work if you changed the `paperClass` function: `console.log($(this)[0].paperElement);`